# How to check if input in valid - by comparing strings in C

Tags: c, string, function

I'm making a calc function which is meant to check if the input is valid. So, I'll have 2 strings, one with what the user inputs (eg, 3+2-1 or maybe dog - which will be invalid), and one with the ALLOWED characters stored in a string, eg '123456789/*-+.^' .

I'm not sure how can I do this and have trouble getting it started. I know a few functions such as STRMCP, and the popular ones from the string.h file, but I have no idea how to use them to check every input.

What is the most simplest way to do this?

Comment: Your question is clear, but you need to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I recommend you read about the [`strpbrk`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) function.

Comment: You have 3 issues on your plate :

1) Validity of the char. meaning numeric and operators only.
2) The order in which the chars are inputted. meaning you can't have 1+2*+5 
3) The calculation itself. Meaning preserving the arithmetic precedence in your calculation.  This is implemented by using a Stack and ordering your characters in a preorder where the operator is placed before the next 2 operands. (Search for a calculator implementation.)

Comment: "*I have no idea how to use them*" did you read the documentation?

Comment: Are you asking about how to use the functions (which ones after all?), about how to get the user input parsed, or for code that solves your problem? I think your question is a bit too broad.

Answer (score 0):

One way of proceeding is the following.

A string is an array of ascii codes. So if your string is

```
char formula[50];
```

then you have a loop

```
int n =0;

while (formula[n]!=0)
  {
     if ( (formula[n]<........<<your code here>>  ))
       {printf("invalid entry\n\n"); return -1; //-1 = error code
     n++;
  }
```

you need to put the logic into the loop, but you can test the ascii codes of each character with this loop.

There may be a more elegant way of solving this, but this will work if you put the correct conditional statement here to check the ascii code of each character.

The while statement checks to see ifyou got to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration of how use `strpbrk()` to check all characters in a string are in your chosen set:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const char alphabet[] = "123456789/*+-=.^";

int main(void) {
  const char a[] = "3+2-1";
  const char b[] = "dog";

  char *res = strpbrk(a, alphabet);
  printf("%s %s\n", a, (res) ? "true" : "false");

  res = strpbrk(b, alphabet);
  printf("%s %s\n", b, (res) ? "true" : "false");

  return 0;
}
```

That's not the fastest way to do this, but it's very easy to use.

However, if you are writing a calculator function, you really want to parse the string at the same time. A typical strategy would be to have two types of entity - operators (`+-/*^`) and operands (numbers, so `-0.1`, `.0002`, `42`, etc). You would extract these from the string as you parse it, and just fail if you hit an invalid character. (If you need to handle parentheses, you'll need a stack for the parsing.... and you'll likely need to work with a stack anyway to process and evaluate the expression overall.)